# How to do nested routing with api response

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

In our current project, my leads want to control everything from admin panel. They want to add/change content of layouts from panel and i have to send request to get layout info to change ui accordingly. And also routes will change dynamically with this response.

I have an api response similar to the following below. I need to get react components with "component" and routes with "url" by using it.

```
[
  {
    "__typename": "Layout",
    "order": 2,
    "title": "{\"en\":\"our services\",\"tr\":\"servislerimiz\"}",
    "is_hidden_from_footer": false,
    "is_hidden_from_header": false,
    "meta_data": null,
    "private_meta_data": null,
    "seo_meta_data": null,
    "category_path": "-",
    "parent_uuid": "-",
    "url": "/our-services",
    "component": "OurServices",
    "children": [
      {
        "__typename": "Layout",
        "order": 3,
        "title": "{\"en\":\"digital transformation\",\"tr\":\"dijital dönüşüm\"}",
        "is_hidden_from_footer": false,
        "is_hidden_from_header": false,
        "meta_data": null,
        "private_meta_data": null,
        "seo_meta_data": null,
        "category_path": "-",
        "parent_uuid": "-",
        "url": "digital-transformation",
        "component": "DigitalTransformation"
      },
      {
        "__typename": "Layout",
        "order": 3,
        "title": "{\"en\":\"Managed IT Services\",\"tr\":\"managed it services\"}",
        "is_hidden_from_footer": false,
        "is_hidden_from_header": false,
        "meta_data": null,
        "private_meta_data": null,
        "seo_meta_data": null,
        "category_path": "-",
        "parent_uuid": "-",
        "url": "managed-it-services",
        "component": "ManagedItServices"
      },
      {
        "__typename": "Layout",
        "order": 3,
        "title": "{\"en\":\"sap consulting\",\"tr\":\"sap consulting\"}",
        "is_hidden_from_footer": false,
        "is_hidden_from_header": false,
        "meta_data": null,
        "private_meta_data": null,
        "seo_meta_data": null,
        "category_path": "-",
        "parent_uuid": "-",
        "url": "sap-consulting",
        "component": "SapConsulting"
      },
      {
        "__typename": "Layout",
        "order": 3,
        "title": "{\"en\":\"Devops\",\"tr\":\"Devops\"}",
        "is_hidden_from_footer": false,
        "is_hidden_from_header": false,
        "meta_data": null,
        "private_meta_data": null,
        "seo_meta_data": null,
        "category_path": "-",
        "parent_uuid": "-",
        "url": "devops",
        "component": "Devops"
      },
      {
        "__typename": "Layout",
        "order": 3,
        "title": "{\"en\":\"application managemenet\",\"tr\":\"application management tr\"}",
        "is_hidden_from_footer": false,
        "is_hidden_from_header": false,
        "meta_data": null,
        "private_meta_data": null,
        "seo_meta_data": null,
        "category_path": "-",
        "parent_uuid": "-",
        "url": "application-management",
        "component": "ApplicationManagement"
      },
      {
        "__typename": "Layout",
        "order": 3,
        "title": "{\"en\":\"QA\",\"tr\":\"QA tr\"}",
        "is_hidden_from_footer": false,
        "is_hidden_from_header": false,
        "meta_data": null,
        "private_meta_data": null,
        "seo_meta_data": null,
        "category_path": "-",
        "parent_uuid": "-",
        "url": "qa-testing-services",
        "component": "QATestingServices"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "__typename": "Layout",
    "order": 3,
    "title": "{\"en\":\"insight\",\"tr\":\"insight tr\"}",
    "is_hidden_from_footer": false,
    "is_hidden_from_header": false,
    "meta_data": null,
    "private_meta_data": null,
    "seo_meta_data": null,
    "category_path": "-",
    "parent_uuid": "-",
    "url": "/insight",
    "component": "Insight",
    "children": [
      {
        "__typename": "Layout",
        "order": 3,
        "title": "{\"en\":\"digital transformation\",\"tr\":\"dijital dönüşüm\"}",
        "is_hidden_from_footer": false,
        "is_hidden_from_header": false,
        "meta_data": null,
        "private_meta_data": null,
        "seo_meta_data": null,
        "category_path": "-",
        "parent_uuid": "-",
        "url": "digital-transformation",
        "component": "DigitalTransformation"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I write this render method but there are warnings.

```
export const RenderRoutes = ({ routes = [] }) => {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<div>loading</div>}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Layout headerData={routes} />}>
            {routes.length &&
              routes.map((item, index) => {
                let Comp = lazy(() => import(`../pages/${item.component}`));

                return (
                  <Route
                    key={index}
                    path={item.url}
                    render={() => {
                      return <Comp />;
                    }}
                  >
                    {item.children.map((child, i) => {
                      let ChildComponent = lazy(() =>
                        import(`../pages/${item.component}/${child.component}`)
                      );

                      return (
                        <Route
                          key={index}
                          path={child.url}
                          render={() => {
                            return <ChildComponent />;
                          }}
                        />
                      );
                    })}
                  </Route>
                );
              })}
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Suspense>
  );
};
```

[image]

So how can I handle this? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've a few issues:

1. In `react-router-dom` v6 the `Route` components no longer have a `component` prop or `render` and `children` prop functions. They were replaced by a single `element` prop taking a `ReactElement`, a.k.a. JSX.
2. The nested inner (*children*) routes are incorrectly using the parent route's `index` as their React keys. Don't use the mapped index, instead use the `url` property as this needs to be unique among sibling routes anyway.
3. Remove the `BrowserRouter` and render only a single router higher in the ReactTree so any links in the app elsewhere can work correctly.

Code:

```
export const RenderRoutes = ({ routes = [] }) => {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<div>loading</div>}>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Layout headerData={routes} />}>
          {routes.map((item) => {
            let Comp = lazy(() => import(`../pages/${item.component}`));

            return (
              <Route key={item.url} path={item.url} element={<Comp />}>
                {item.children.map((child) => {
                  let ChildComponent = lazy(() =>
                    import(`../pages/${item.component}/${child.component}`)
                  );

                  return (
                    <Route
                      key={child.url}
                      path={child.url}
                      element={<ChildComponent />}
                    />
                  );
                })}
              </Route>
            );
          })}
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Suspense>
  );
};
```